# Elastic search filter not working for multi value json

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-query

Hi My elastic search index has the mapping as.

```
"userId": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "userId": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "userName": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Also my search query looks like this
GET : http://localhost:5000/questions/_search

Body is

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        { "term": { "userId.userId": "testuser@demo.com"
        }}
   
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I am always getting 0 hits. Is there a better value to query multivalue json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`userId.userId` field is of `text` type. If no analyzer is defined, elasticsearch by default uses a [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html). This will tokenize `testuser@demo.com` into

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "testuser",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 8,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "demo.com",
      "start_offset": 9,
      "end_offset": 17,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

You need to use `"userId.userId.keyword"` field on the `userId.userId` field. This uses the keyword analyzer instead of the standard analyzer (notice the ".keyword" after userId.userId field).

**You are getting 0 hits, because the [term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html), always searches for exact matching term. And as you are using the standard analyzer (which is the default one) for searching, you will not get correct results**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "userId.userId.keyword": "testuser@demo.com"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to search for multiple fields use the [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html)

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "userId.userId.keyword": [
              "testuser@demo.com",
              "abc.com"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Update 1:**

You can use the `must_not` clause along with the term query to get all records that have userId not equal to `testuser@demo.com`

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": {
        "term": {
          "userId.userId.keyword": "testuser@demo.com"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is working. thanks . Is there way to get the opposite of this. To get all records that have userId not equal to testuser@demo.com

Comment: @slaveCoder yes you can do that using `must_not` clause. Please go through the updated part of the answer

Answer (score 1):

Terms query returns documents that contain one or more exact terms in a provided field.The terms query is the same as the term query, except you can search for multiple values.

```
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "userId.userId": [ "testuser@demo.com", "other@demo.com" ],
      "boost": 1.0
    }
  }
}
```